# Duality and corrections to second-order gravity without and with torsion terms

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, topological-field-theory, gauss-bonnet

Recently, there appeared a paper by Giacomo Pollari, [A Nieh-Yan-like topological invariant in General Relativity](http://arxiv.org/abs/2302.00584), where the action for gravity looks like:

$$S_g=S_{EHP}+S_{HO}+S_{PO}+S_{GB}+S_{NY}+S_{ET}$$

and where

$$S_{EHP}=\alpha_0\int e^I\wedge e^J \wedge \star R_{JI}$$

is the Einstein-Hilbert-Palatini action term,

$$S_{HO}=\alpha_1\int e^I\wedge e^J \wedge R_{JI}$$

is the Holst action

$$S_{PO}=\alpha_2\int R^{IJ}\wedge R_{JI}$$

is the Pontryagin action

$$S_{GB}=\alpha_3\int R^{IJ}\wedge \star R_{JI}$$

is the Gauss-Bonnet term

$$S_{NY}=\alpha_4\int d(e^I\wedge T_I)$$

is the topological Nieh-Yan action, and the new exotic (dual) torsion term reads

$$S_{ET}=\alpha_5\int d(e^I\wedge \star T_I)$$

The above whole action is suggestively dual symmetric under the following transformations:

$$\alpha_0 \star R_{IJ}\leftrightarrow \alpha_1 R_{JI}$$

(interchanging EHP with HO)

$$\alpha_3 R^{IJ}\leftrightarrow \alpha_3 \star R_{JI}$$

(interchanging the Gauss-Bonnet term with itself)

$$\alpha_4 T_I\leftrightarrow \alpha_5 \star T_I$$

(interchanging the Nieh-Yan topological term with the exotic dual torsion term)

provided we supplement a further seventh term to the action, the (double)-dual term to the Pontryagin action

$$S_{DP}= \alpha_6 \int\star R^{IJ}\wedge \star R_{JI}$$

such as changing $R^{IJ}$ by its dual $\star R^{JI}$ the whole action is totally symmetry after substituting $R$ and $T$ by their duals, provided

$$\alpha_2 R^{IJ}\wedge R_{JI}\leftrightarrow \alpha_6 \star R^{IJ}\wedge \star R_{JI}$$

(that interchanges the Pontryagin action with its double dualized action, $S_{DP}$).

With these transformations the complete action seems to be invariant under the above duality. However, to be more precise, is the doubly dual of the Pontrjagin action a sensible meaningul action?  Furthermore, what could be the physical interpretation of this duality transformation and the meaning of every action term? I thought this question because I can find out natural the the GB and PO terms are "self-dual" to theirselves (being topological), and also I can understand somehow torsional topological NY being dual, but I can not figure out why EHP should be "dual" to the Holst action after this duality. Has it any sense?

Comment: *Am I right to just suggest this duality?* This site doesn’t do peer review of proposed theories.

Comment: Not an answer but something to note. This paper states the term identified is 'new', yet this is clearly false. This term has been identified for at least 50+ years, e.g., in Teleparallel gravity: it is simply the boundary term appearing in the relation between the Levi-Civita Ricci scalar and the torsion tensor, $R = - T + B$. I suspect the author either has missed a large portion of literature, or been ignorant of the fact that the term written in tensor notation is very familiar.

Comment: @Eletie Surely it can be unknown. I did not know that and I have read about Chern-Simons theories, non-metric theories (but teleparallel gravity is usually "ugly" for outsiders, too much cumbersome notations and not an easy shorthand notation make it unpleasant! Chern-Simons (super)gravities are more "nice" surely due to the anomaly role of CS (2n+1)-forms but teleparallelism looses a good looking intro!). What about my crazy idea of and additional *R*R term? Is it known from differential geometry such a term?

Comment: @riemannium I can assure you it has been known (I have used it in my own work for example). If you prefer less ugly notation, take a look at some work by Hehl in the 70s to 90s, you will definitely find this term (e.g., https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(94)00111-F).  I also agree with you about cumbersome notation though. I'm not sure about your additional term (without doing the calculations) have you checked that it's topological, and that it is not somehow equivalent to any of the original terms?

Comment: @Eletie I am not sure either! But *R*R even if "classically equivalent" up to a boundary term, it could be proportional to some kind of theta term... Duality is appealing in my notation above taken from the articles and Cartan language, but I would not ensure if *R*R is equivalent totally at the quantum level...

Comment: @riemannium If you do calculate this, post an answer to your own question (as I'd be interested in the result). It'd also likely answer your question of whether it's a sensible term to include.

Comment: @Eletie Only with one condition: to quote this thread and question if you use it in papers. I have a bad experience when I proposed the dark compact object for Planet Nine some years ago and NO ONE quoted my suggestion/idea. So, if I include the calculation, please, you will cite this page (and I can give you my name if necessary if you contact me with the links provided in the URLs at my blog -web available in my biopic here).

Comment: @Eletie Indeed, *R*R=**RR, and depending on the signature it can be $\star^2=\pm 1$, so you were right...Indeed, one could add *R*R as a counterterm and nullify RR term with certain spacetime dimension. The CS term I was thinking of is R*R (only one dual) and it is certainly related to topological CS-like terms. I don't think it is too relevant *R*R then finally unless you use it as counter-term of the Pontrjagin term. So duality would explain the absence of Pontrjagin term in certain spacetime dimensions, and or enlarge it...suitable...if **R=R

Comment: @riemannium Ah nice, this makes a lot of sense then. (I probably should have been able to see this myself by inspection but I haven't worked with this notation for a while).